# How to find custom duplicates entries within a list of objects using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm importing a list of people from CSV that contains duplicate people with different ids. (IOW, the person was entered twice into the system that generated the CSV).  Once I import the list and map it to an internal object, I now need to identify duplicates in the `List<Person>`.

I would consider two people to be a match if their ids do not match and one or more of the following are the same:

1. Social Security and Lastname

OR

2. Firstname, Lastname and Birthdate

In SQL, I would do something like the following:

```sql
select p1.id, p2.id
 from persons as p1
 join persons as p2
 where p1.id != p2.id
 and ( (p1.SSN != null AND p1.SSN = p2.SSN AND p1.Lastname = p2.Lastname)
 or (p1.Firstname = p2.Firstname AND p1.Lastname = p2.Lastname AND p1.Birthdate != null AND p1.Birthdate = p2.Birthdate) )
```

How do I accomplish this using a `List<Person>` and Linq?

Comment: Please show us your attempt, what's not working and steps to reproduce. We can help, but without code we can't give an adequate answer, otherwise people will just be slinging code around that may and or may not even address the issue you are having.

Comment: `list.Where(p => <your conditions>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the linq query syntax which is very similar to sql that you wrote:

```
var duplicates =
    from p1 in persons
    from p2 in persons
    where p1.Id != p2.Id && (
        (p1.SSN == p2.SSN && p1.LastName == p2.LastName) ||
        (p1.FirstName == p2.FirstName && p1.LastName == p2.LastName && p1.BirthDate == p2.BirthDate))
    select new { Person1 = p1, Person2 = p2 };
```

Comment: Hmm, for some reason I was thinking you had to use the `join` keyword when using multiple sources.  Thanks!

Comment: `join` is when you want to merge the results from more than one source into a single result. Same as with sql. linq is designed to model query language, the keywords are (mostly) 1-1

Comment: Curious why someone down voted this response as it does seem to actually solve the problem.  If you downvote, please explain why this is not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Using a Linq comprehension query**

Perhaps it may exist a better solution using Linq lambda but you can use that:

```
var query = ( from p1 in persons
              from p2 in persons
              where p1.id != p2.id
                 && ( ( p1.SSN != null && p1.SSN == p2.SSN && p1.Lastname == p2.Lastname )
                   || ( p1.Firstname == p2.Firstname && p1.Lastname == p2.Lastname
                     && p1.Birthdate != null && p1.Birthdate == p2.Birthdate ) )
              select new { person1_ID = p1.id, person2_ID = p2.id }
            ).ToList();

// Remove duplicates results
foreach ( var item in query.ToList() )
  if ( query.Contains(new { person1_ID = item.person2_ID, person2_ID = item.person1_ID }) )
    query.Remove(item);
```

I haven't checked your condition logic and I took the same you wrote.

**Using a double loop on persons is fastest and consumes less memory**

```
var duplicates = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

foreach ( var p1 in persons )
  foreach ( var p2 in persons )
    if ( p1.id != p2.id
      && ( ( p1.SSN != null && p1.SSN == p2.SSN && p1.Lastname == p2.Lastname )
        || ( p1.Firstname == p2.Firstname && p1.Lastname == p2.Lastname
          && p1.Birthdate != null && p1.Birthdate == p2.Birthdate ) ) )
      if ( !duplicates.Contains(new Tuple<int, int>(p2.id, p1.id)) )
        duplicates.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(p1.id, p2.id));
```

**Test data**

```
public class Person
{
  public int id;
  public string SSN;
  public string Firstname;
  public string Lastname;
  public DateTime? Birthdate;
}

var persons = new List<Person>();

persons.Add(new Person { id = 1, Firstname = "a", Lastname = "a", Birthdate = null, SSN = "1" });
persons.Add(new Person { id = 2, Firstname = "b", Lastname = "b", Birthdate = null, SSN = "1" });
persons.Add(new Person { id = 3, Firstname = "a", Lastname = "a", Birthdate = null, SSN = "1" });
```

**Test Linq**

```
foreach ( var item in query )
  Console.WriteLine($"{item.person1_ID} <=> {{item.person2_ID}}");
```

**Test loop**

```
foreach ( var item in duplicates )
  Console.WriteLine($"{item.Item1} <=> {item.Item2}");
```

**Output**

```
3 <=> 1  // Linq

1 <=> 3  // Loop
```

**Benchmark**

Looping 1000000 times on each solution gives:

```
1646ms  // Linq with remove duplicates results
1323ms  // Linq without remove duplicates results

359ms   // Loop
```

Comment: `I'm importing a list of people from CSV that contains duplicate people with different ids.`, the user has one list that has all records, not two. How would this solution work with only one list?

Comment: Thanks for the completeness of your answer!  I didn't realize that Linq was so much slower than just looping through the items myself!

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to achieve this is to use LINQ `.GroupBy`:

```
var duplicatedNamesAndBirthdate = persons
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.FirstName, p.LastName, p.BirthDate })
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key,        
        g => g.ToArray()
    );

foreach (var pair in duplicatedNamesAndBirthdate)
{
    Console.WriteLine(@$"{pair.Value.Length} people have the duplicated info: 
FirstName={pair.Key.FirstName}, 
LastName={pair.Key.LastName}, 
BirthDate={pair.Key.BirthDate}.");
}
```

The dictionary will contain anonymous objects with the duplicated data as keys, and array of duplicated `Person`s as value.

By the way, in SQL it would be more efficient to use `group by` too instead of self-joining the table.

Comment: You only addressed one of the potential match options.  Is it still more efficient if I have to perform two `.GroupBy` twice and then somehow join the results to get a single list?